# how to make module in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, module

i am making a joomla website i am very new in joomla so finding some problem during work.

i have done slider for my joomla 2.5 template now i have a problem i have to make three boxes which i have already made in html css link given below

http://uttaraclick.com/malta/

can any one tell me what is the best solution for this problem , i don't know how the module works but i read that it possible with the customized module.

Please help

and i have already read this http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_(MVC)_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_01
and next also

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what your problem is.

Comment: Lodder, have you seen the link that i have given above you would be able to see the three boxes at there. I want to make it three box text would be access from the article which we have post. and want these three boxes only display on the home page.

Comment: Why not just use a Custom HTML module for each of those boxes, i.e. 3 modules? Just stick your content in there and restyle a little bit.

Comment: but how i would able to use it only in home page.

Comment: You can assign them to appear on the homepage only by going into each module and selecting them to appear for the "Home" menu item only.

Comment: only one problem i have already show the design to client and he want it as it is. ): so could not change the design.

Comment: you won't need to change the design. see my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I think the best way would be to create 3 custom module positions for your template, then use 3 Custom HTML modules, allowing you to type in your content and so on.

This will also allow you to assign the module to the Homepage only.

For more information on creating custom module positions, read this:

http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_add_a_new_module_position%3F

---

To generate a basic module to save you time, you could try this:

http://agjoomla.com/en/tools/mvc-module-generator.html

Make sure you select the Joomla 1.6 version and once downloaded, you open the XML file and change `version="1.6"` to `version="2.5"`

---

As for the design, nothing will have to be different. You can assign the boxes a class, then give that class the same styling in the css file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you help is so valuable for me

Comment: Please let me know how could i make a module faster. is there any online tool so that can help me to make these module faster.                 Or joomla has any option from where i can make it.

Comment: @DevelopmentBucket - I can upload my beta module generator, or you could try [this](http://agjoomla.com/en/tools/mvc-module-generator.html). You have the option of selecting Joomla 1.6, so once you have downloaded the module, make sure you change the version in the .xml file to 2.5 ;)

Comment: @Lodder - Man am I glad I looked in this thread. Your generators are excellent. Really nice time saving resource. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Trev, your welcome :) If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as correct, by clicking the "tick" button to the left of the question.

Comment: @Lodder Thanks for sharing really nice tool Great

Comment: @Trev am using your method "Custom HTML module " that worked for me Thanks i always googling the things that i don't know but stack overflow provide the great medium in taking advice from you kind of experts.